# Transition flickering

Tags: javascript, transition, d3.js

I see a strange flickering effect after a transition. It is unusual mainly because I do not set the opacity in any way (I want the color to remain the same). Any ideas why this happens?
To have an idea about how the code looks like, here is an example.

```
var theBars = this.vis.selectAll(".bar" + source.id).data(this.columns);

theBars.enter().insert("svg:rect")
       //some attributes
        .style("fill", sourceColor)
        //some other attributes

theBars.transition()
        //.duration(.01)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
                return this.settings.base - this.getStackedBarHeight(d, source.id);
            }.bind(this))
        .attr("height", function(d) {
                return this.getBarHeight(d.counters[source.id]);
            }.bind(this));
```

As it can be seen only one line sets the color.
I initially tought I made some mistakes at binding, but after checking some posts here and on Google Groups, I discovered that this flickering usually appears when you have transitions that also change the opacity of the object. Unfortunately I don't change any opacity, I just make a transition. This effect appears in all major browsers when executing that transition (theBars.transition).

I try to select a bar from a stacked bar and modify its height.

Best regards!

Comment: What browser(s) are you using when you see the flickering?

Comment: In all 4 of them: Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE.

Comment: The selectAll statement seems a bit strange to me, leading me to guess it might have something to do with inserting duplicate rect elements, but it is hard to say without seeing the whole thing - would it be possible to duplicate this problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can really duplicate everything...first of all the entire code has several thousands of lines...even the part that has to be built in order to execute this snippet has around 200 lines....and this function is called from another function that's executed at the end of a certain transition...there are no duplicates, each bar being drawn only once... I checked this multiple times...however, I just discovered that the bars were not initialized anywhere. I will fix this tomorrow morning. So thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hmm, took just 2 minutes to fix the initializations, but the error is still there... that was not the problem. I still think it has something to do with the transition....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this I added 2 things:

1. in the init phase - I added all the bars but with all counters set
   on 0;
2. in the draw phase - I added this code:

   ```
   var theBars = this.vis.selectAll("#bar_"+index+"_"+currentIndex);

   this.settings.sources.each(function(pair) {
        theBars
            .style("fill", source.color)
            .attr("height", this.getBarHeight(source.id)
            .attr("y", this.settings.size.baseLine - this.getStackedBarHeight(counters, source.id))
   }, this);
   ```

The flickering caused by the transitions is gone since we have no transition here. There are still situations in which we need to do a transition, for example when we have several bars with the same word, but there I resolved the flickering by doing it really quick (a .duration(.1) or even less).